# Select max sum for each year in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a SQLite database that tracks information on board games (name, year published, mechanics, publishers, number of people who own it on www.boardgamegeek.com, and boardgamegeek's current rank for that game).  The schema is:

[image: Schema for database]

I'm interested in getting the most popular mechanic (the mechanic that has the highest number of copies owned) per year for a specific publisher.  The current query I have is:

```
select games.year as yr, mechanics.name as mech, sum(collection.owned) as sm
 from games 
 inner join gamemech on games.bggid = gamemech.bggid
 inner join mechanics on gamemech.mechid = mechanics.mechid
 inner join gamepub on gamepub.bggid = games.bggid
 inner join publishers on publishers.pubid = gamepub.pubid
 inner join collection on collection.bggid = games.bggid
 where publishers.name like '%stronghold%'
 group by yr, mech order by yr limit 20;
```

This returns:

```
1974|Commodity Speculation|1460
1974|Dice Rolling|1460
1974|Tile Placement|1460
1982|Action Point Allowance System|16111
1982|Dice Rolling|16111
1982|Modular Board|16111
1982|Secret Unit Deployment|16111
1985|PaperandPencil|1949
1991|Auction/Bidding|1266
1992|Grid Movement|1704
1992|Pickup and Deliver|1704
2011|Action Point Allowance System|7943
2011|Area Control / Area Influence|174
2011|Area Movement|3607
2011|Auction/Bidding|174
2011|Card Drafting|5133
2011|Deck / Pool Building|3768
2011|Dice Rolling|2385
2011|Hand Management|5663
2011|Line Drawing|2141
```

What I'm really interested in is just the year, mechanic, and the sum of copies owned for whatever mechanic has the highest sum each year.  Like this (ties can be broken however):

```
1974|Commodity Speculation|1460
1982|Action Point Allowance System|16111
1985|PaperandPencil|1949
1991|Auction/Bidding|1266
1992|Grid Movement|1704
2011|Action Point Allowance System|7943
```

I think I might need another select statement in the query, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution just hit me.  If you find yourself here, this is how I did it:

I basically wanted to get the max(sum()) of each group.  Firs thing you need to do is figure out the query that has all of the data (this is the first query I had).  For me, it is:

```
select games.year as yr, mechanics.name as mech, sum(collection.owned) as sm
 from games 
 inner join gamemech on games.bggid = gamemech.bggid
 inner join mechanics on gamemech.mechid = mechanics.mechid
 inner join gamepub on gamepub.bggid = games.bggid
 inner join publishers on publishers.pubid = gamepub.pubid
 inner join collection on collection.bggid = games.bggid
 where publishers.name like '%stronghold%'
 group by yr, mech order by yr limit 20;
```

What this returns is in the main question.  Next, we want to select from that.  I'm interested in:

```
games.year, mechanics.name, max(sm)
```

The trick is that each table in the first query needs to be named (for me this is yr, mech, and sm) so that you can join to it later.  The final query is:

```
Select games.year, mechanics.name, max(sm) from (
select games.year as yr, mechanics.name as mech, sum(collection.owned) as sm
 from games 
 inner join gamemech on games.bggid = gamemech.bggid
 inner join mechanics on gamemech.mechid = mechanics.mechid
 inner join gamepub on gamepub.bggid = games.bggid
 inner join publishers on publishers.pubid = gamepub.pubid
 inner join collection on collection.bggid = games.bggid
 where publishers.name like '%stronghold%'
 group by yr, mech)
inner join games on games.year = yr
inner join mechanics on mechanics.name = mech
group by yr;
```

I hope that makes sense!